# SparkSession configuration at the Job level is not getting applied; Spark Cluster configuration is overriding it

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, statsd

I am trying to get the spark default metrics from the application to statsd sink at Job level not cluster level. So I configured the necessary configuration in the Spark session in code. And in a local system, which means a single node, while it is running, I am able to receive all the UDP packets. While in the AWS DataBricks (SingleNode or MultiNode) cluster, I deployed the same jar. But there, I am not getting any metrics. But if I override the Spark config in Advance Options -> Compute in Databricks. I am able to receive metrics. And configurations are reflected in the Environment Variables.

[image: SparkSession configuration code]]
[image: AWS Databricks -> Compute -> Advance Options -> Spark Config cluster]

I tried updating "metrics.properties" using InitScript in the databricks cluster. I am not able to see the values in Environment Variables in the Spark UI. And also overrode the spark session configuration again after the spark session creation. And I am printing the spark configuration values in the console. Still Not reflecting the environmental Variables.[image: Spark Config override after spark session]

Comment: Can you try setting in sparkcontext instead of spark session? Also may be try changing default values in  spark-submit to see if that works(if so we can have separate submits  for different jobs as a immediate wordaround)

Comment: @VindhyaG tried by updating the sparkcontext but it was not reflecting. If i killed the existing sparkcontext and creating a new one means. The configuration was reflecting. But after sometimes the application was shutting down with this issue. (com.timgroup.statsd.StatsDClientException: Failed to start StatsD client
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: maximum number of DatagramSockets reached). But if i enabled the metrics via cluster. It was running fine. I am not getting any socket exception

Comment: So you mean sparkcontext reflects the conf changes  but fails after a while and spark-submit works without issue ?

Comment: Yes sparkcontext refects the conf changes only if i we kill the existing sparkcontext. Which was created by default in databricks. After a while the application fails. I wont tried the spark-submit yet.